# service nginx start is ok but nginx not running

Tags: 14.04, server, nginx

I have a ubuntu 14.04 machin with nginx, which was working fine until I last used my computer that was last night. Today when I started my computer and navigated to 127.0.0.1 it said server not found so I tried restarting nginx nginx start was successful but I had the same issue on 127.0.0.1 so I checked netstat -ntlp where I did not see port 80 anywhere. I am not sure what went wrong and clueless about it. Here is the nginx log :

> 2015/03/22 17:50:10 [alert] 5030#0: unlink() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 7):

**Problem:**

It is because by default **Apache** and **nginx** are listening to the same port number (:80)

1. Reconfigure **nginx** to listen on a different port by following these steps:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
   ```
2. Change all ports `:80` to `:8000` or another unused port number.
3. **Check if the configuration is correct:**

   ```
   sudo service nginx configtest
   ```
4. **Restart nginx:**

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart
   ```
5. **Check the status of nginx:**

   ```
   sudo service nginx status
   ```

**Note:** You can also check on your browser whether **nginx** is working:

```
http://localhost:8000
```